# POST 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I'm going mad with this error.

`POST
http://localhost:56105/Home/getContactbyId?ConId=%225%22 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Hope you'll be able to help me. I need to get Contact data based on ContactId. Following is the relevant code (apologies if I missed something, I'll add if needed):

contactController.js

```
ContactsApp.controller("contactController", function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, myService) {
     function getContactById(id) {
         var getting = myService.get_Contact_By_Id(id);    
         getting.then(function successCallback(response) {
             $rootScope.Name = response.data.Name;
         }, function errorCallback(response) {
             return "Error";
         });
     }
    function init() {
        var contactId = $location.path().split("/")[2];
        console.log(contactId); //this loggs the correct Id
        getContactById(contactId);
    }
    init();
}
```

myService.js

```
ContactsApp.service("myService", function ($http) { 
    this.get_Contact_By_Id = function (ConId) {
    console.log(ConId);  //this logs the correct id
    return $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/Home/getContactById',
        params: {
            ConId: JSON.stringify(ConId)
        }
    });
  }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
     public string getContactById(int ConId)
     { 
         int id_int = Convert.ToInt32(ConId);
         using (ContactsDBEntities contactsData = new ContactsDBEntities())
         {
             var theOne = contactsData.Contacts.Where(x => x.Id == id_int).FirstOrDefault();
             return theOne.Name;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: A status of 500 means an error on the server-side. Have you set breakpoints on the server-side code to see where it's breaking, or tried logging your exceptions?

Comment: As @ADyson pointed out you need to debug your server side code. Set break points and attach your IDE. If you cant do that then add some logging.

Comment: Seems quotes are being added around your ConId as @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez says above... Decoded URL - http://localhost:56105/Home/getContactbyId?ConId="5"

Comment: Did you try with `ConId` instead `JSON.stringify(ConId)`?

Comment: in your home controller is a few flaw.
1. Why do you cast int to int? ConId is already an int so why do you bother with it ?
2. FirstorDefault returns Null for reference types. So if you try to reach a property of a null obejct you will get a NullReferenceException. You should check it first just like:
return theOne?.Name;
It will simply return null without trying to reach the Name property if it is already null.
Also if it is a WebApi controller you should inherit the controller from ApiController and not from Controller.

Comment: an other thing you could try is to wrap the whole logic inside the Controller and if there is any error you can just return its message.

Comment: If you don't know where to put breakpoint in your controller - start with overriding OnException method and set breakpoint there.

Answer (score 3):

Using `JSON.stringify(ConId)` returns a quoted string with the `ConId` number. `params` expects a simple object with `name : value` pairs. Simply use

```
params: {
            ConId: ConId
        }
```

When the `ConId` is sent using `stringify()`, the `Convert.ToInt32(ConId)` call will throw an Exception for conversion (expected NUMBER, not 'NUMBER'). You should put some validation after using that conversion, or a try - catch block.

Also it could be a problem with returning `FirstOrDefault()` if no result is found. You should check also the `theOne` variable before using it.

You should check the server application log  (Application Event Viewer) to see the exception causing the HTTP Error 500.